# Illegal string offset, how to work with this data

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array returned from an API call like below. When I try to access the data using its key, I get an illegal string offset. I believe it's caused by the fact that the key names don't have `'` around them, but I can't do any thing about that as the data is coming from an external source.

Any idea why this is happening or what I can do about it ?

```
 [data] => Array
        (
            [latest] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 123.59000
                    [value_int] => 12359000
                    [display] => $123.59000
                    [display_short] => $123.59
                    [currency] => USD
                )
```

im trying to access the data like this

```
     echo $element['value'];
```

Comment: I doubt that you receive an array written in PHP like this. How do you process the API return?

Comment: correct, its part of a larger multi dimensional array, ive updated as above

Answer (score 4):

If you are looping your `$array`, you already have value in `$element` variable.

You can expand also array`s keys with:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo $key . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

If you want to access value with key, just use without looping:

```
echo $array['value'];
```

According to your edit - if you have large array assigned to the `$array` variable, loop array value assigned to `data` key with:

```
foreach ( $array['data'] as $element ) {
    echo $element['value'];
}
```

Comment: cheers, ive got that in and although its outputting correctly, but im still getting the Warning: Illegal string offset 'display_short' on the echo $element['value']; line

Comment: In what context do you use `display_short` key ? Does the `$element` array contains `display_short` key ?

Comment: yeah, its in the same array as 'value'

Comment: You should post your full code containing `display_short` to let me check it.

Comment: sure, thanks for the help on this, `foreach ($array['data'] as $element){
 echo $element['display_short'];
}` and the array is the same as in the original question

Comment: Try to `var_dump($element)` in every loop to check array's content.